What is the translation of the word "ibn" that some Rabbis have in their name?
For example R. Chisdai ibn Shaprut, his full name is R Chisdai ben Yitzchak ibn Shaprut. So that "ibn" cant be translated as "son of".

It means son in Arabic but doesn't typically denote a father-son relationship but rather the patriarch by which the family is known
(Eg Ramban Bamidbar 26:13:

אבל הענין כי היה המנהג בישראל לעשות להם ראשי בתי אבות, יתיחסו כל יוצאי יריכו לעולם אל האיש ההוא, ויקראו על שמו לכבודו, כאשר יעשו גם היום כל הישמעאלים וכל ישראל הדרים בארצותם להקרא כולם למשפחות אבן עזרא, אבן שושן. וזה טעם: אלה ראשי בית אבותם (שמות ו':י"ד), כי מעת אשר פרו ורבו במצרים העמידו להם ראשי משפחות להתיחס אליהם. ואולי התחילו בענין הזה במצרים, שלא יתערבו בגוים ויהיו ניכרים וידועים לשבטיהם, ששם עלו שבטים שבטי יה עדות לישראל,⁠ ותהי לחק בישראל.
But [we must say that] this matter was [as follows]. It was the custom in Israel [for people] to appoint over themselves "heads of fathers' houses," and all the descendants of that man would always trace their lineage back to him, and be called by his name in his honor; just as all the Arabs do to this very day, and as do all the Jews who live in their [the Arabs'] countries, calling themselves by family [names, such as] "Ibn Ezra," or "Ibn Shushan." This is the meaning of the verse which says, These are the heads of their fathers' houses,⁠ for from the time that they were fruitful and multiplied in Egypt, they established heads of families over themselves, to whom they would trace their lineage. Perhaps they initiated this practice in Egypt in order not to mingle themselves with the nations and so that they would be recognized and distinguishable among their tribes, [for it is there in Egypt] whither the tribes went up, even the tribes of the Eternal, as a testimony unto Israel,⁠ and it became a custom in Israel.⁠

(HT @b a & TY @RabbiKaii for the suggestion)

examples include ibn ezra and ibn haviv families: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ibn_Habib

It's analogous to "ben" in Hebrew.

Arabic has bin بن and the similar ibn ابن - if you see both together in somebody's name then bin will usually mean "son of ..." while ibn will usually mean "descended from ...".

Missing the crucial reason so many Jewish scholars have Arabic in their name - because they lived in relative peace and often held high positions in Muslim Andalucia, especially compared to the Christian kingdoms before and after, and because we know about most of them through those Muslim sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_age_of_Jewish_culture_in_Spain.

@RabbiKaii Here's another (Meiri Gittin 34b): וזה שאמרו בפרק אחרון כתב חניכתו וחניכתה כשר פירושו על שצריך לכתוב שמו ושם אביו וזה כתב שמו ולא כתב שם אביו אלא שהוסיף על שמו חניכת המשפחה כגון שכתב אברהם אבן עזרא ולמד שאותה חניכה עומדת במקום שם האב
